# iOS :App crash on [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-sdk-4.0

when i logged in with FBlogin it get loggedin successfully & on click of logout Logout also get successfully but if i removed from background or rerun project which has bloggedin & try to logg out app get crashes ….same function working with without removing from background & but not working on relaunch
 function:

```
[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
```

@abstract Logs the user out
 @discussion This calls `[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]` and `[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil].`

```
- (void)logOut
```

also i tried to logout  with these two method 
`[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]` and `[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil].`

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between 'new' and 'alloc init'. Try the following:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *fbManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[fbManager logOut];
```

Comment: What is the difference in this case?